# Fixing bad sectors on Apple Snow Leopard

Tags: hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, bad-sectors

I'm running Snow Leopard and have found some bad sectors on my hard drive. Looks like I'm in need of a fix here.

How do I go about fixing these bad sectors? Is there a program or tool that I can use to fix this?

Comment: http://uncoy.com/2006/09/bad_sector_io_e.html

Comment: [Fix bad blocks on Mac hard disk](http://superuser.com/q/148227/84988) (2010-06-02) and note that in some cases, the user may wish to recover data before auto-relocation –  writing data to the drive will [most likely result in volume or data corruption if a bad block is found and spared](http://superuser.com/a/576380/84988).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hard drive truly has a bad sector, then try Tech Tool Pro v5.
But if you have bad sectors, it typically is a unrepairable issue.  Bad sectors should be transparently mapped out using spare sectors on the hard drive.

If you are seeing it at the user level, then your hard drive is dying.  Back up your data, and purchase a new hard drive.

Comment: thank you, i'm gonna give tech tool pro a chance. it has more then just hard drive tests, it tests your all computer and that's something i should use.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have look on this page which has very good information about  it bad secrtors removal [programs](http://uncoy.com/2006/09/bad_sector_io_e.html)

Comment: Please give me reason for Down vote ?

Comment: thanks for the link, but i saw there only backup utilities not bad sector marking solutions.