# Checking number of reallocated sectors of HDD through Disk Utility, Mac OS X

Tags: macos, macbook, hard-drive

My macbook was purchased in 2008. Yesterday I checked number of reallocated sectors of HDD through Disk Utility. It showed there were no any reallocated sector. That seems strange, I didn`t renew my HDD since 2008. As for reallocated sectors, can I rely on Disk Utility or I need to download additional software?

Comment: better to ask this on SuperUser SO's sister site.

Comment: ...or even Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Disk Utility is only reporting back the SMART status from the physical drive. Most manufactures don't report the reallocated sectors during the initial format. And then, some don't report future ones at all. That said, you may simply have a good quality drive and have treated it well.  I have a 40GB drive from a PowerBook that it still going strong without a single bad sector.

Answer (score 0):

> … can I rely on Disk Utility or I need to download additional software?

Disk Utility alone is limited to basic interpretation of available S.M.A.R.T. data.

There are some S.M.A.R.T.-related suggestions under [Fix bad blocks on Mac hard disk](https://superuser.com/q/148227/84988) (2010-06-02) (but as noted in one of the answers, reallocation is not always desirable (not necessarily a *fix*)).